# Linux: Use TabletPC as Drawing Tablet for PC

Tags: linux, graphics-tablet, tablet-pc

Since my tablet pc isn't really strong (or the screen really big...) I'm working with CAD on my tower, currently only with keyboard and mouse. Now I would like to use my tablet pc as a graphics tablet for my PC - but couldn't find any tools for that occasion yet.

VNC/general RDC tools won't work since the screen of the laptop is much smaller than the screen itself, so I would have to scroll for almost every step.
Synergy, sadly, doesn't provide such functionality.

I came here because it seems that this is a more specialized question. Is there a program or script, that makes it possible to use the tablet pc as a tablet?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
TabletPC: Fedora 20; Tower: Fedora 19

Comment: I've been looking for one for years.  No such luck.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from an app that allows you to emulate a mouse with your tablet (see [WIFMOUSE](http://wifimouse.necta.us/)) over wifi, you are pretty much out of luck.

You can scale the remote screen from your tablet so that the full resolution of your computer fits, but this will dramatically decrease your precision.

Comment: The problem is, that Apps like WIFMOUSE only work for Android - not natively for linux. But thanks, guess i will have to remain on working with a mouse =/

Comment: There is a wifi mouse server for linux! What kind of tablet PC OS are you using on your tablet?  From your question, I assumed Android.

Comment: My tabletpc runs fedora (it's not a tablet of the recent generations like an iPad or Nexus 10 - it's an IBM Thinkpad x61t). Though apps won't run natively^^

Comment: Should have been more specific about that, I added the information to the question.